# How can I get grep piped through tac to return value without killing the process in php exec() function?

Tags: php, grep, shell-exec

I am trying to find the most recent access of 'foo' in nginx access.log and when I run the following command through command line, it works exactly as expected and very quickly.

```
$output = exec('tac /var/log/nginx/access.log | grep -m1 "foo"');
echo $output;
```

However, running it through php's `exec()` function, it times out after 30 some seconds.  If I kill the `tac` process on the server, PHP will output the expected result as soon as the process is killed.  I have tried

```
grep "foo" /var/log/nginx/access.log | tail -1
```

but that takes a full 22 seconds to find a result instead of a fraction of a second in the command line, but again doesn't work through the PHP `exec()` function.

Thank you for any assistance you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this in PHP with standard file read functions [`fopen()`](http://php.net/fopen) and friends:

```
<?php
$fname = "/var/log/nginx/access.log";
$pos = 0;
$matches = [];
$search = "foo";
$limit = 3;
$line = "";

$f = fopen($fname, "r");
while (fseek($f, $pos, SEEK_END) !== -1) {
    $char = fgetc($f);
    if ($char === PHP_EOL) {
        if (strpos($line, $search) !== false) {
            $matches[] = $line;
            if (count($matches) === $limit) {
                break;
            }
        }
        $line = '';
    } else {
            $line = "$char$line";
    }
    $pos--;
}
fclose($f);
print_r($matches);
```